# Apply function to create multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply

As the title suggests I am looking for a method to apply a function for every row in my data frame and create multiple new columns, regarding to one column.

So what I mean by this, is that I have a df containing the names of different cities. Now I want to create 2 new rows containing the size of population, the country, the founding date and maybe some more infos.

I have an API that returns those infos as a json. So far so good.
What I am currently doing is using a for loop to go through the df, make an api call and then set the columns using iloc... its not really nice or efficient.

I am wondering if I could produce a similar outcome using an apply/transform function.

my current solution:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print("--------------------->" + str(index))
    try:
        infos = cityInfo.download(row["city"],row["zip"])
    except:
        break
    if len(infos) == 0:
        print("City not found!")
    else:
        data["pop"].iloc[index] = infos["population"]
        data["country"].iloc[index] = infos["country"]
        data["founding"].iloc[index] = infos["foundingDate"
```

I am happy for any help or hint

Comment: Please show some minimal example for reproducing your input and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Pandas documentation:

> You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect.

So for a start, I would iterate over the index and reference that dataframe. (I haven't written in your try-except statement but add it if needed).

I assumed your API did something like this:

```
class cityInfoAPIDummy:
def __init__(self):
    self.data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["city","zip","population","country","foundingDate"],data=[["london","NE1","100000","UK","ages ago"],["birmingham","B","50000","UK","less long ago"]])
def download(self,city,z):
    return self.data[self.data["city"]==city][self.data["zip"]==z]
```

The code to do what you want to do with an apply() function is then like below:

```
def get_info(city,z,field):
    cityInfo=cityInfoAPIDummy()

    infos = cityInfo.download(city,z)

    if len(infos)==0:
        print("City not found")
        return ""
    else:
        return infos[field].values[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # assuming some dummy data in the format you were after
    data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["city","zip"],data=[["london","NE1"],["birmingham","B"]])
    data["pop"] = data.apply( lambda x: get_info(x["city"],x["zip"],"population") ,axis=1)
    data["country"] = data.apply(lambda x: get_info(x["city"],x["zip"],"country"),axis=1)
    data["founding"] = data.apply(lambda x: get_info(x["city"],x["zip"],"foundingDate"),axis=1)

print(data)
```

I hope this is helpful, but it is hard to know what the API serves you if it is a custom API.

Answer (score 1):

Do not expect good answers to a problem involving an API that noone here has insight to. Calling the API in each iteration of the loop is probably the slow part. If your API doesnt allow downloading all the info in a single call, you probably won't be able to increase the performance much.
Also, apply/transform (when taking in rows) will do basically the same thing, calling the API [no. of rows] times. Taking in columns, these methods won't take two columns at the same time.